# Is it possible to tile the hat polykite with smaller copies of itself?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, tiling

The [recently discovered](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.10798.pdf) monotyle known as the *hat* is a polykite that tiles the plane aperiodically. A tiling looks like this:

[image]

I wonder whether it is possible to tile this 13-edge hat-shaped figure with smaller copies of itself. These copies may be rotated any number of degrees, and flipped. I suppose there are two variants of this **question**:

1. Can the hat polykite be tiled with a finite amount of smaller copies of itself that are each of the same size? If so, how many smaller copies are required?
2. If not, is it possible to tile the hat with a finite amount of smaller copies of itself that are of different sizes? If so, how many different sizes are needed, and how many copies of each size ought to be used?

Comment: My understanding of the terminology is that an *einstein* is any shape that only tiles the plane aperiodically; this particular einstein has its own name, which is the *hat* (or *hat polykite* if you prefer something more formal).

Comment: @MishaLavrov I see, thank you for the clarification. Will edit the question accordingly

Comment: I suspect this is impossible - here's my intuition.  Consider one 'face' of the hat. If we could tile it with smaller copies of itself, we'd need to somehow make a 'long' straight face with several small copies of the hat, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Just try placing a *hat* into a right angle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is impossible, even allowing different sized hats.

Every internal angle of the hat has a measure of at least $90^\circ$, and there are exactly four right angles, marked A, B, C, and D in the image below. There needs to be some smaller hat which covers the vertex of angle D. Because the smallest angle is $90^\circ$, the point of smaller tile over vertex D must be one of the vertices A, B, C, or D. However, A, B, and C are impossible, because each of these angles have a neighboring reflex angle which measures greater than $180^\circ$, which would force the smaller hat to just out of the larger hat. Therefore, the smaller hat would have to have its D vertex aligned with the D vertex of the large tile. But this creates a different problem; since both of the angles next to D measure $120^\circ$, the smaller hat tile at D would create a $180^\circ-120^\circ=60^\circ$ angle in the leftover space, and the hat has no angle small enough to fit inside a $60^\circ$ angle. Therefore, there is no way to tile a hat with smaller hats.

[image]